# How to update the google infowindow on real time basis

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Is there any way to update the google infowindow on real time basis
let suppose the content is:

- the sum is 21
- mobile number
- available quantity 200

where the value of the sum and the quantity is variable and must be updated whether the infowindow is opened or not if opened then the values must reflect over the infowindow when changed.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the infowindow are arbitrary html.  You could certainly wrap your values in a span and update them as you see fit.  There wouldn't be any need to update the html if the infowindow is not visible.  Just update the variables.